# stored procedure running continuosly in background

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am using one class file for updating my tables. In that I am either inserting or updating tables and after each update or insert, I am calling one stored procedure to save the last updated ID of the table. But once this stored procedure runs it never releases the resource. It is executing always in background. Why is this happening and how can I stop it?
Here is the stored procedure:-

```
Create  procedure [dbo].[Updlastusedkey]

                 (

                   @tablename varchar(50)

                 )

as

Begin

DECLARE @sql varchar(300)

SET @SQL='UPDATE   primarykeyTab   SET  lastKeyUsed = ISNULL(( SELECT Max(ID) from '+@tablename +'),1) WHERE Tablename='''+@tablename +''''

print @SQL

EXEC(@SQL)
```

END

Comment: what do you mean by not releasing the resources? how do you know? your proc looks fine.

Comment: as a side question: how this query finds last updated row?

Comment: suppose i inserted one row in table A and then called stored procedure, after running SP , when i am trying to do any operation with table A , it is not allowing . while i can access other tables .

Comment: @knvn:-i am using this for last inserted ID..sorry for word updation

Comment: Multiple tables use essentially the same primary key column? That doesn't sound like a good idea. But why aren't you using the SCOPE_IDENTITY() function?

Comment: or use a simple sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have Auto-Commit turned on?  I think  implicit_transactions = OFF means Auto Commit = ON in SQL Server.  If not your Update operation may not be executing a COMMIT for the transaction it opened so leaving a write lock on the table.  Alternatively just explicitly COMMIT your update perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a view?

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vPrimaryKeyTab
AS
    SELECT tablename = 'table1', MAX(id_column) FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT tablename = 'table2', MAX(id_column) FROM table2
    /* ... */
;
```

Now you don't need to update anything or run anything in the background, and the view is always going to be up to date (it won't be the fastest query in the world, but at least you only pay that cost when you need that information, rather than constantly keeping it up to date).

Comment: yes you are right. i can do it by other way also and it is working.but i was wondering that why this approach is not working..

Comment: Well I'm not sure anyone knows what your statements "not working" and "not allowing" mean...

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
UPDATE   primarykeyTab   SET  lastKeyUsed = ISNULL(( SELECT Max(ID) from '+@tablename 
+' WITH (NOLOCK)),1) WHERE Tablename='''+@tablename +'''' WITH (NOLOCK)
```